# Remove string shorter than k from a list of strings

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings  like the following:

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc',  'aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc']
```

And I need to extract only the strings with k=4 characters, so the output would be:

```
minlist = ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc']
```

How can be implemented efficiently ?

Comment: You need to create an empty list before a for-loop to iterate through your mylist. Then, you use an if conditional to append each iteration with len(4) into your empty list.

Comment: @K.Land_bioinfo Yes but it would be very computational demanding in general case, i thought there could be something more efficient

Comment: I understand. I'm still fairly new to programming, so I am not the best at tips and tricks to making code more efficient yet.

Comment: @Georgy it was similar and the anwser I accepted is more specific to my problem. There is no need to close the question

Comment: @roygbiv It's normal practice to close a question as a duplicate of a broader one. There is nothing bad about that. Your question will not be deleted and will stay as a signpost pointing people towards the canonical duplicate target. For more info see [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates), [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/378331).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly the type of situation the [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function is intended for:

```
>>> mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc',  'aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc']
>>> minlist = list(filter(lambda i: len(i) == 4, mylist))
>>> minlist
['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc']
```

`filter` takes two arguments: the first is a function, and the second is an iterable. The function will be applied to each element of the iterable, and if the function returns `True`, the element will be kept, and if the function returns `False`, the element will be excluded. `filter` returns the result of filtering these elements according to the passed in function

As a sidenote, the `filter` function returns a `filter` object, which is an iterator, rather than a `list` (which is why the explicit `list` call is included). So, if you're simply iterating over the values, you don't need to convert it to a `list` as it will be more efficient

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
def get_minlist(my_list, k):
    return [item for item in my_list if len(item) == k]
```

You can use this as:

```py
print(get_minlist(["abc", "ab", "a"], 2))
```

Result:

```
['ab']
```

The code is pythonic, fast, and is very easy to understand. The code goes through the items in the list, checks if they are `k` in length, if so it keeps them.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the length of a string using `len()`.

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc',  'aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc']
minlist = [x for x in mylist if len(x) == 4]
```

Result:

```
['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc',  'aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc']
minilist=[]

for i in range (len(mylist)):
    if len(mylist[i]) == 4:
        minilist.append(mylist[i])

print(minilist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comment, you could try something like this:

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc',  'aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc']

newlst=[]
for item in mylist:
    if len(item) == 4:
        newlst.append(item)

print (newlst)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
'mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc',  'aaaa', 'bbbb', 'cccc']
```

here we are using the concept called as list comprehension,list comprehension means it is a easy way to create a list based on some iterables.
note:-iterable is something which can be looped over
during list comprehension creation  elements from the iterables(ex:-mylist) can be conditionally included in the new list and transformed as needed

syntax of list comprehension:-

note:-  this symbol '|' is used to tell syntax as three parts,1st 2 parts are mandatory and the last part is optional

```
[give me this | from the collection | with this condition ]

[mandatory    |  mandatory          |    optional ]

[var for var in iterables condition ] 

filtered_list=[item for item in mylist if len(item)==4]
print(filtered list)
```